# Apache2 proxying HTTPS web pages

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I need to proxing of HTTPS pages, that hidden behind router.

```
Public internet 
-> Router 
-> port forwarding 443 
-> first apache2 web server 
-> need proxying to my second apache2 web server
```

I'm port forwarding port 443 to my first local server (where is first.example.com running on 443), but second.example.com runs on sencond web server. And I need set proxy on first server to proxing me pages from second server.

I tried to edit Apache2 virtual host

```
<VirtualHost second.example.com:443>
...
 ProxyPass / https://second.example.com/
 ProxyPassRewerse / https://second.example.com/
...
</VirtualHost>
```

FIRST PROBLEM is that first Apache2 ignore VirtualHost second.example.com at all... because in local DNS second.example.com is routed to real second.example.com

SECOND PROBLEM when I change DNS to second.example.com routed to first server. ProxyPass rule to new DNS record https://second-on-second.example.com
than my browser did not show content of HTTPS comunication, because od SNI error... because now certificate didn't coresponding domain. Same error will ocurrect, when I change ProxyPass to IP of second server.

Could me anybody help how do working proxying of web

Answer (score 0):

The `VirtualHost` should BE `first.example.com`, doing a reverse proxy to `second.example.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName first.example.com
    ...
    ProxyPass / https://second.example.com/
    ProxyPassRewerse / https://second.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, if both of the web servers are inside your NAT, `second.example.com` isn't probably resolving to your internal IP address (lets say `second A 192.168.0.2`), which may cause a second problem.

If you need to have `second.example.com` in the `Host:` header, because the second sever only responds correctly with that virtual host name (and that name is also in its TLS certificate), add `192.168.0.2 second.example.com` in the `/etc/hosts` of your first server.

If you don't need to have TLS inside your internal network, use plain HTTP between the servers:

- On the second server

  - use `<VirtualHost *:80>` without TLS.
  - add `ServerAlias 192.168.0.2` to make it work without `/etc/hosts`.
- On the first server, have the following reverse proxy configuration:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName first.example.com
      ...
      ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.2/
      ProxyPassRewerse / http://192.168.0.2/
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

Comment: I think, that this solution, will create more problems, that solves. VirtualHost *:443 means force SSL certifikate to all host, and all host would be interpreted as this one :( finally server2 would have SSL certificate of server1... means bad domain certificate

Comment: "`VirtualHost *:443` means force SSL certifikate to all host" **No, it doesn't.** Read the documentation on [`<VirtualHost>` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) to know what the `addr` in it means. It must not be confused with [`ServerName` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) – and even that won't force TLS, like [HSTS](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797) does.

Comment: Hi, only one solution works for me. Change deklaration of to local IP of first server. It means this <VirtualHost 10.0.0.11:443>! I tryed <VirtualHost *:443> and it did not work, because apache ignore VirtualHost declaration at all :( So thanks, for direction of right way.

Comment: So you are using my solution, but `<VirtualHost 10.0.0.11:443>` instead of `*:433`? If so, you could accept / upvote. The difference you have there is related to something else in your configuration, but the `ServerName` and `ProxyPass` in my answer should be needed to achieve your goal.